# Swift : Verify Core Data Attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have a Swift application with Core Data that stores the following:

- Username
- Email
- Key

I have a ViewController to collect this information correctly setup and it is storing this information within core data. There is a textfield for all 3 attributes with a save button and it saves.

I have another Storyboard ViewController which has a Textfield for the "key" and a Button to Verify the key along with a label to display wether the key is accepted or not.
When the user enters the correct key a "Continue Button" Appears

My Problem:
At this moment my application retrieves the information and displays the saved info in my console. However, it doesn't check for the key specifically and allows any information to the Continue Button.
How do I call the Attribute instead of the whole entity and use that info to allow continuing?
I assume I would have to access the Entity to retrieve the attribute, but how do I do this?

Here is my code for the Verify Button:

```
 @IBAction func verifyKey()
{

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if (results.count > 0)
    {
        btnContinueAppears.hidden = false
        keyLabel.text = "Key Accepted"
        keyLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        keyLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        for res in results
        {
            println(res)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnContinueAppears.hidden = true
        keyLabel.text = ("Key Denied, Access Denied")
        keyLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        keyLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        println("0 Results Returned...Potential Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the object from array, and then access its attribute like this,

```
@IBAction func verifyKey()
{

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if (results.count > 0)
    {
        let aResult = results.first! as NSManagedObject
        btnContinueAppears.hidden = false
        keyLabel.text = "Key Accepted"
        keyLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        keyLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        for res in results as [NSManagedObject]
        {
          let textColor = res.valueForKey("color")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnContinueAppears.hidden = true
        keyLabel.text = ("Key Denied, Access Denied")
        keyLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        keyLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        println("0 Results Returned...Potential Error")
    }
}
```

If you have not assigned class to the entity, then you should use kvc getter methods to access the value of attributes using, valueForKey:. Otherwise you could simply use the class and access attributes like accessing properties of a regular class.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding this line:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key = %@", "" + keyEnter.text)
```

I have added it after the:

```
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

This worked and is checking the key within the database.

Thank you respectfully for your feedback. :)